# How to filter dictionary of dataframes by size?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, anomaly-detection

I have dictionary of dataframes which contains over 2000 different dataframes.
Key is index(combination of 3 columns-like plant,material,workcenter) value is the data which contains different measurements.

I want to work on outlier detection but some dataframes in that dictionary has 1 or 2 records.
So I want to eliminate these dataframes from the dictionary. I searched but there are very few info about how to do that. Can you help?

Maybe I approach in wrong direction, what do you suggest instead?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dict estructure and a few records? If not, a generic answer is use: df.shape[0]. It gives you the number of rows in a dataframe.

Comment: `len(dataframe)` gives you the number of records.  Loop through your collection to purge those which don't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about, if `d` is your dictionary:

```py
filtered_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in d.items() if len(v) > 100}  # Or any number you'd like to filter by
```